# Microservices - Should you separate user accounts from profile information?

Tags: microservices

For example:

Accounts Microservice - Handles authentication and stores email, password.

Profile Microservice - Fetched when displaying identity information name, age, gender, address, etc.

Or is this overkill and just a single Users Microservice would suffice?

Comment: I would say try different approach...it's not that difficult with microservices and choose what makes the best sense according to your situation.

Comment: Depends on the bounded context and size of your service. If the authentication logic is very small, it makes sense to combine it with user profile data.

Comment: In any case, I would name them `Authentication` (not `Accounts`) and `UserProfile`.